# Connecting a single event to a specific method in wxWidgets

Tags: c++, events, wxwidgets

I'm making my first steps in learning wxWidgets. I learnt how to assign events to Menu Items or Buttons for example, because they do have IDs. But when I tried to assign an event to a Menu, I found it real difficult.

My aim was to asign one of those top Menus from the MenuBar a specific event, rather than them having a list of Menu Items. At first I didn't manage it, until I thought on using:

```
Connect(wxEVT_MENU_OPEN, wxCommandEventHandler(MainFrame::Config));
```

This worked fine, until I realized this now happens to all Menus! Which is evident though, as there is no place where I specified the Connect command to apply *only* for that Menu.

Any help here? I'd like that method to be executed *just* when a specific Menu is clicked, but not all! Thanks in beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you want MainFrame::Config to be called if the menu item created by

```
yourMenu->Append(SOME_ID, wxT("&Configuration"));
```

gets clicked, use

```
this->Bind(wxEVT_COMMAND_MENU_SELECTED, &MainFrame::Config, this, SOME_ID);
```

if *this* is your mainframe.

Comment: Thanks, its almost working, though the compiler is returning me this error: "expected unqualified-id before '->' token". It might be because the Menu I'm talking about is, well, a wxMenu class, not a wxMenuItem class, and hence it does not have an ID. What I did was put the wxMenu identifier where you said SOME_ID, is that fine as well?

Comment: What wxMenu identifier do you mean? 
The error message sounds as if the *this* pointer was off.

Comment: By identifier I mean the name I gave to the menu when declaring it: "wxMenu *ConfigMenu = new wxMenu();", so the name is "ConfigMenu".

Comment: No, the pointer ist no valid identifier. In fact, wxMenu can not have an ID so if you really want to listen to the wxEVt_MENU_OPEN event, you will have to check for the menu inside your listener.

Comment: I see, I'll see what I can do with this.